# Apache oozie under Hue

Tags: oozie

I need a step-by-step documentation to set up a workflow scheduler with oozie under hue with the configuration or parameterization steps.
I have a school project: "Workflows for the Big Data" or one asks me to use oozie for the scheduling of tasks in hadoop I do not know at all. After searching on the internet (site of apache oozie, site of hue and documentation) and in some books I do not find satisfactory result.
However I defined some job in xml files but when I try to systematically oozie it kills the job. I'm new to the forum and big data

Comment: 1. How to configure a job under oozie under hue?
2. How to specify a job tracker under hue?
3. How do I set up an input and output directory?

Comment: Look into the "Hooked for Hadoop" blog, there's a nice tutorial about Oozie in there. But nothing about the Hue job editor UI, because (1) I don't think it existed back in 2013 and (2) that toy UI just covers the simplest of Oozie features, it's not fit for Production usage (let alone Continuous Integration...)